# Reset jquery after click

Tags: jquery, reset

Can someone help me.

http://beibl.users32.interdns.co.uk/second.php

Their is the website i am working on if you click the computer screen link in the middle nav, it will alert a popup and load content from a div using prettyphoto which is great exactly what i want.

Heres the code.

```
$("ul.second-menu a.first[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'facebook'});

$("ul.second-menu a.first").click(function() {
var text = $(".inner-content").html();
var h2 = $("h2.sec-main").html();
$(".inner-content-op").append(text);
$(".header-ow h2").append(h2);
return false;
});
```

My issue is if you close the lightbox and re-open it, it will load the content back in again so its their twice ho do i reset the jquery back to its intial state after the lightbox is closed.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you are appending to the element.

If you change append function, like below

```
$(".inner-content-op").append(text);
$(".header-ow h2").append(h2);
```

to something like html function, like below

```
$(".inner-content-op").html(text);
$(".header-ow h2").html(h2);
```

It will overwrite all html within the element, rather than appending to it.
Here is your result:

```
$("ul.second-menu a.first[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'facebook'});

$("ul.second-menu a.first").click(function() {
var text = $(".inner-content").html();
var h2 = $("h2.sec-main").html();
$(".inner-content-op").html(text);
$(".header-ow h2").html(h2);
return false;
});
```

Comment: Brilliant i love stackoverflow fair play

Answer (score 0):

You can either empty the $(".inner-content-op") and $(".header-ow h2") elements everytime you click or you can instead of using append() you can use html() function.